# Bought BTC from Blockchain but Received Less Than Expected

Tags: blockchain.info

Recently, I bought £350 worth of bitcoins back when they where £37 the other day. They've taken over a day to get through to me and when I have received them I only have 7.7 (compared to the 9.1 that I need). I appears they have charged me at today's prices instead of the ones that where the current price the other day. Even though when I purchased the coins it said I was buying £350@37 a coin.

Is it normal practice to do this?

Comment: When you say they took over a day, was that a day when they had your money? Or was that a day before the money got to them? How did you pay? By what method?

Comment: I gave them the money on "Day 1" at 3:00pm when the going rate was £37 a coin. I paid via PingIt so I think it should be almost instant. I recieved my bitcoins on "Day 3" at 5am when the going rate was about £42 a coin.

I hope this clears things up.

Comment: That sounds like a problem. You should talk to them.

Comment: Same problem here. Their mobile phone number goes to answerphone but I've sent an email following up my original support request.

Comment: Im glad to hear Im not the only one. I assume its due to the sudden surge in bitcoin purchases. Ill try calling them now.

Comment: Right, just called up and it looks like Barclays (The owners of pingit) where completely overwhelemed at the point and so where slow to process it. The person I talked to was very helpful and is going to send me the extra amount now.  I contacted him at this number: (+44) 7525 431876

Comment: Thanks Marche. The person I spoke to just now was also very helpful and we seem to have resolved the issue (related to trying two transactions at once). I must say I'm very impressed with their customer service. Edited to add: fixed, within 10 minutes.

Comment: @Marche101 Post that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Right, just called up and it looks like Barclays (The owners of PingIt) where completely overwhelemed at the point and so where slow to process it. The person I talked to was very helpful and is going to send me the extra amount now. I contacted him at this number: (+44) 7525 431876.

In hindsight, I think they where just incredibly busy with orders and so where slow putting it through.